# Sorting a list using Lambda/Linq to objects

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-to-objects

I have the name of the "sort by property" in a string. I will need to use Lambda/Linq to sort the list of objects.

Ex:

```
public class Employee
{
  public string FirstName {set; get;}
  public string LastName {set; get;}
  public DateTime DOB {set; get;}
}


public void Sort(ref List<Employee> list, string sortBy, string sortDirection)
{
  //Example data:
  //sortBy = "FirstName"
  //sortDirection = "ASC" or "DESC"

  if (sortBy == "FirstName")
  {
    list = list.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName).toList();    
  }

}
```

1. Instead of using a bunch of ifs to check the fieldname (sortBy), is there a cleaner way of doing the sorting
2. Is sort aware of datatype?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606997/linq-order-by-for-a-listof-myobjects

Comment: I see *sortBy == "FirstName"*. Did the OP mean to do *.Equals()* instead?

Comment: @Pieter he probably did mean to compare equality, but I doubt he "meant to do .Equals()". Typo's usually don't result in code that functions.

Comment: @Pieter Your question only makes sense if you think there's something wrong with `==` ... what?

Answer (score 415):

This can be done as

```
list.Sort( (emp1,emp2)=>emp1.FirstName.CompareTo(emp2.FirstName) );
```

The .NET framework is casting the lambda `(emp1,emp2)=>int` as a `Comparer<Employee>.`

This has the advantage of being strongly typed.

If you need the descending/reverse order invert the parameters.

```
list.Sort( (emp1,emp2)=>emp2.FirstName.CompareTo(emp1.FirstName) );
```

Comment: It often happened to me to write complex comparison operators, involving multiple comparison criteria and a failsafe GUID comparison in the end to ensure antisymmetry. Would you use a lambda expression for a complex comparison like that? If not, does this mean that lambda expression comparisons should only be limited to simple cases?

Comment: The questions says the property is "in a string"

Comment: yeah i dont see it either something like this?  list.Sort( (emp1,emp2)=>emp1.GetType().GetProperty(sortBy).GetValue(emp1,null).CompareTo(emp2.GetType().GetProperty(sortBy).GetValue(emp2,null)) );

Comment: So, I tried that, but I'm getting "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<MyType>' because it is not a delegate type."

My code: _queries.Sort((item1, item2) => item.Name.Equals(item2.Name));

Comment: For the record, I got around the error message via using an explicit instance of Comparer<Query>, but I'm curious as to what went wrong.

Comment: Two years late for Ari Roth but for anyone wondering, you need to use .CompareTo(...), not .Equals(...).

Comment: how to sort in reverse?

Comment: @JerryGoyal swap the params... emp2.FirstName.CompareTo(emp1.FirstName) etc.

Comment: Just because it's a function reference doesn't it has to be a one liner.
You could just write `list.sort(functionDeclaredElsewhere)`

Answer (score 75):

One thing you could do is change `Sort` so it makes better use of lambdas.

```
public enum SortDirection { Ascending, Descending }
public void Sort<TKey>(ref List<Employee> list,
                       Func<Employee, TKey> sorter, SortDirection direction)
{
  if (direction == SortDirection.Ascending)
    list = list.OrderBy(sorter);
  else
    list = list.OrderByDescending(sorter);
}
```

Now you can specify the field to sort when calling the `Sort` method.

```
Sort(ref employees, e => e.DOB, SortDirection.Descending);
```

Comment: Since the sort column is in a string you'd still need a switch/if-else blocks to determine which function to pass it.

Comment: You can't make that assumption. Who knows how his code calls it.

Comment: He stated in the question that the "sort by property" is in a string.  I'm just going by his question.

Comment: True, but maybe it's only in string form because he didn't know he could use lambdas to sort it like this?

Comment: I think it's more likely because it's coming from a sort control on a web page that passes the sort column back as a string parameter.  That would be my use case, anyway.

Comment: @tvanfosson - You are right, I have a custom control that has the order and the field name as a string

Comment: @tvanfosson "Since the sort column is in a string you'd still need a switch/if-else blocks to determine which function to pass it. " -- No, you don't ... you can have a Dictionary<string, Func<Employee, TKey>>. The OP asked for something cleaner, and this gets part way there. It should also get rid of that awful `ref` and return the sorted list (changing the name of the method from `Sort` to `Sorted`).

Answer (score 56):

You could use Reflection to get the value of the property.

```
list = list.OrderBy( x => TypeHelper.GetPropertyValue( x, sortBy ) )
           .ToList();
```

Where TypeHelper has a static method like:

```
public static class TypeHelper
{
    public static object GetPropertyValue( object obj, string name )
    {
        return obj == null ? null : obj.GetType()
                                       .GetProperty( name )
                                       .GetValue( obj, null );
    }
}
```

You might also want to look at  Dynamic LINQ from the [VS2008 Samples library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb330936.aspx).  You could use the IEnumerable extension to cast the List as an IQueryable and then use the Dynamic link OrderBy extension.

```
 list = list.AsQueryable().OrderBy( sortBy + " " + sortDirection );
```

Comment: While this does solve his problem, we might want to steer him away from using a string to sort it. Good answer none-the-less.

Comment: You can use Dynamic linq without Linq to Sql to do what he needs...I love it

Comment: Sure. You can convert it to IQueryable.  Didn't think about that.  Updating my answer.

Comment: @Samuel If the sort is coming in as a route variable there is no other way to sort it.

Comment: @AlexFord Yes there is. If the sort is coming in as a route variable you will get it as a string. You can generate a lambda expression for the property using this string.

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method GetPropertyValue method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Comment: @ChuckD - bring the collection into memory before you attempt to use it, e.g. `collection.ToList().OrderBy(x => TypeHelper.GetPropertyValue( x, sortBy)).ToList();`

Answer (score 23):

This is how I solved my problem:

```
List<User> list = GetAllUsers();  //Private Method

if (!sortAscending)
{
    list = list
           .OrderBy(r => r.GetType().GetProperty(sortBy).GetValue(r,null))
           .ToList();
}
else
{
    list = list
           .OrderByDescending(r => r.GetType().GetProperty(sortBy).GetValue(r,null))
           .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Building the order by expression can be read [here](http://www.singingeels.com/Blogs/Nullable/2008/03/26/Dynamic_LINQ_OrderBy_using_String_Names.aspx)

Shamelessly stolen from the page in link:

```
// First we define the parameter that we are going to use
// in our OrderBy clause. This is the same as "(person =>"
// in the example above.
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "person");

// Now we'll make our lambda function that returns the
// "DateOfBirth" property by it's name.
var mySortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, object>>(Expression.Property(param, "DateOfBirth"), param);

// Now I can sort my people list.
Person[] sortedPeople = people.OrderBy(mySortExpression).ToArray();
```

Comment: There are problems associated with this: DateTime sort.

Comment: Also how about composite classes, ie Person.Employer.CompanyName?

Comment: I was essentially doing the same thing and this answer solved it.

Answer (score 8):

You could use reflection to access the property.

```
public List<Employee> Sort(List<Employee> list, String sortBy, String sortDirection)
{
   PropertyInfo property = list.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].
                                GetType().GetProperty(sortBy);

   if (sortDirection == "ASC")
   {
      return list.OrderBy(e => property.GetValue(e, null));
   }
   if (sortDirection == "DESC")
   {
      return list.OrderByDescending(e => property.GetValue(e, null));
   }
   else
   {
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
   }
}
```

**Notes**

1. Why do you pass the list by reference?
2. You should use a enum for the sort direction.
3. You could get a much cleaner solution if you would pass a lambda expression 
   specifying the property to sort by instead of the property name as a string.
4. In my example list == null will cause a NullReferenceException, you should catch this case.

Comment: Has anyone else ever noticed that this is a return type void but returns lists?

Comment: At least no one cared to fix it and I did not noticed it because I did not write the code using an IDE. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 6):

Sort uses the IComparable interface, if the type implements it.
And you can avoid the ifs by implementing a custom IComparer:

```
class EmpComp : IComparer<Employee>
{
    string fieldName;
    public EmpComp(string fieldName)
    {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
    }

    public int Compare(Employee x, Employee y)
    {
        // compare x.fieldName and y.fieldName
    }
}
```

and then

```
list.Sort(new EmpComp(sortBy));
```

Comment: FYI: Sort is a method of List<T> and is not a Linq extension.

Answer (score 5):

**Answer for 1.:**

You should be able to manually build an expression tree that can be passed into OrderBy using the name as a string. *Or* you could use reflection as suggested in another answer, which might be less work.

*Edit*: Here is a working example of building an expression tree manually. (Sorting on X.Value, when only knowing the name "Value" of the property). You could (should) build a generic method for doing it.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class Program
{
    private static readonly Random rand = new Random();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var randX = from n in Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
                    select new X { Value = rand.Next(1000) };

        ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(X), "value");
        var expression = Expression.Property(pe, "Value");
        var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<X, int>>(expression, pe).Compile();

        foreach (var n in randX.OrderBy(exp))
            Console.WriteLine(n.Value);
    }

    public class X
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Building an expression tree requires you to know the particpating types, however. That might or might not be a problem in your usage scenario. If you don't know what type you should be sorting on, it will propably be easier using reflection.

**Answer for 2.:**

Yes, since Comparer<T>.Default will be used for the comparison, if you do not explicitly define the comparer.

Comment: Do you have an example of building an expression tree to be passed into OrderBy?

Answer (score 5):

The solution provided by Rashack does not work for value types (int, enums, etc.) unfortunately.

For it to work with any type of property, this is the solution I found:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, object>> GetLambdaExpressionFor<T>(this string sortColumn)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
        var body = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameterExpression, sortColumn);
        var convertedBody = Expression.MakeUnary(ExpressionType.Convert, body, typeof(object));

        var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(convertedBody, new[] { parameterExpression });

        return expression;
    }
```

Comment: This is awesome and even properly gets translated to SQL!

Comment: thank you for the Expression.MakeUnary code example. This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public static class EnumerableHelper
{

    static MethodInfo orderBy = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).Where(x => x.Name == "OrderBy" && x.GetParameters().Length == 2).First();

    public static IEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, string propertyName)
    {
        var pi = typeof(TSource).GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var selectorParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "keySelector");
        var sourceParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<TSource>), "source");
        return 
            Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<TSource>, IOrderedEnumerable<TSource>>>
            (
                Expression.Call
                (
                    orderBy.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TSource), pi.PropertyType), 
                    sourceParam, 
                    Expression.Lambda
                    (
                        typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TSource), pi.PropertyType), 
                        Expression.Property(selectorParam, pi), 
                        selectorParam
                    )
                ), 
                sourceParam
            )
            .Compile()(source);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, string propertyName, bool ascending)
    {
        return ascending ? source.OrderBy(propertyName) : source.OrderBy(propertyName).Reverse();
    }

}
```

Another one, this time for any IQueryable:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

public static class IQueryableHelper
{

    static MethodInfo orderBy = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).Where(x => x.Name == "OrderBy" && x.GetParameters().Length == 2).First();
    static MethodInfo orderByDescending = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).Where(x => x.Name == "OrderByDescending" && x.GetParameters().Length == 2).First();

    public static IQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, params string[] sortDescriptors)
    {
        return sortDescriptors.Length > 0 ? source.OrderBy(sortDescriptors, 0) : source;
    }

    static IQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, string[] sortDescriptors, int index)
    {
        if (index < sortDescriptors.Length - 1) source = source.OrderBy(sortDescriptors, index + 1);
        string[] splitted = sortDescriptors[index].Split(' ');
        var pi = typeof(TSource).GetProperty(splitted[0], BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
        var selectorParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "keySelector");
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TSource>(Expression.Call((splitted.Length > 1 && string.Compare(splitted[1], "desc", StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0 ? orderByDescending : orderBy).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TSource), pi.PropertyType), source.Expression, Expression.Lambda(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TSource), pi.PropertyType), Expression.Property(selectorParam, pi), selectorParam)));
    }

}
```

You can pass multiple sort criteria, like this:

```
var q = dc.Felhasznalos.OrderBy(new string[] { "Email", "FelhasznaloID desc" });
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what @Samuel and @bluish did.  This is much shorter as the Enum was unnecessary in this case.  Plus as an added bonus when the Ascending is the desired result, you can pass only 2 parameters instead of 3 since true is the default answer to the third parameter.

```
public void Sort<TKey>(ref List<Person> list, Func<Person, TKey> sorter, bool isAscending = true)
{
    list = isAscending ? list.OrderBy(sorter) : list.OrderByDescending(sorter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get sort column name and sort direction as string and don't want to use switch or if\else syntax to determine column, then this example may be interesting for you:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<IuInternetUsers, object>>> _sortColumns = 
        new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<IuInternetUsers, object>>>()
    {
        { nameof(ContactSearchItem.Id),             c => c.Id },
        { nameof(ContactSearchItem.FirstName),      c => c.FirstName },
        { nameof(ContactSearchItem.LastName),       c => c.LastName },
        { nameof(ContactSearchItem.Organization),   c => c.Company.Company },
        { nameof(ContactSearchItem.CustomerCode),   c => c.Company.Code },
        { nameof(ContactSearchItem.Country),        c => c.CountryNavigation.Code },
        { nameof(ContactSearchItem.City),           c => c.City },
        { nameof(ContactSearchItem.ModifiedDate),   c => c.ModifiedDate },
    };

    private IQueryable<IuInternetUsers> SetUpSort(IQueryable<IuInternetUsers> contacts, string sort, string sortDir)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sort))
        {
            sort = nameof(ContactSearchItem.Id);
        }

        _sortColumns.TryGetValue(sort, out var sortColumn);
        if (sortColumn == null)
        {
            sortColumn = c => c.Id;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortDir) || sortDir == SortDirections.AscendingSort)
        {
            contacts = contacts.OrderBy(sortColumn);
        }
        else
        {
            contacts = contacts.OrderByDescending(sortColumn);
        }

        return contacts;
    }
```

Solution based on using Dictionary that connects needed for sort column via Expression> and its key string.