# How can I improve this sorting code?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm checking the sort parameter and building a bunch of `if` statements:

```
if (sortDirection == "ASC")
{
    if (sortBy == "Id")
        return customerList.OrderBy(x => x.Id).Skip(startIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList();
    if (sortBy == "FirstName")
        return customerList.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName).Skip(startIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList();
    if (sortBy == "City")
        return customerList.OrderBy(x => x.City).Skip(startIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList();
}
else
{
    if (sortBy == "Id")
        return customerList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Skip(startIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList();
    if (sortBy == "FirstName")
        return customerList.OrderByDescending(x => x.FirstName).Skip(startIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList();
    if (sortBy == "City")
        return customerList.OrderByDescending(x => x.City).Skip(startIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList();
}
```

How do I make this better?

Comment: Define "better". Better for what?

Comment: In what way do you want to "improve" it? Does it not work as intended? Is it too slow? Do you not like how the code is structured? We need more information here.

Comment: I would recomend using LINQ composition. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881107/how-can-i-build-entity-framework-queries-dynamically/5882243#5882243

Comment: Create a dictionary of delegates and then call them basing on the key(s).

Comment: It'd be nice if it can be more dynamic where I don't need to add if statements just because a new sortBy string has been sent in.

Comment: Not too familiar with C# syntax, but one way I would try to do it would be to use a hashmap to store the string(ex: Id) to objects(ex x.Id) associations and just retrieve your orderBy keys from that hashmap.

Comment: See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493274/linq-sort-direction-from-string

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Separate your ordering and the rest of the query - the parts that are the same for each query you don't have to duplicate in your codebase (keep it [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)):

```
var query = customerList;

if (sortDirection == "ASC")
{
    if (sortBy == "Id")
       query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Id);
    ///and so on
}

query = query.Skip(startIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

Comment: That's still a lot of boilerplate for all the fields, wouldn't reflection be much cleaner? Imagine if he had 50 fields! :)

Comment: @NiklasB. That would be problem, because OrderBy is generic and the lambda has different type for every property. Unless you want to convert it to object everywhere.

Comment: @mattytommo: That's certainly possible and neat if this is an in-memory collection

Comment: @Euphoric: Oh, that certainly would be a problem. I don't know C# too well :)

Comment: @Euphoric - You could create a `Dictionary<string,IComparable>`.

Comment: @ElianEbbing But then, you cannot use LINQ, but need to apply this to the list itself.

Comment: @Euphoric - Ehm, I meant `Dictionary<string,Func<MyType,IComparable>>`. I typed too fast ;)

Comment: @Elian: Yeah, something like that is what I had in mind too. Functions should be contravariant in the argument types and covariant in the return value, which seems to be the case in C# as well.

Comment: @ElianEbbing I still dont know what are you going to do with IComparable in LINQ. Check OrderBy method signatures. There is no IComparable everywhere. It only needs function to return value, that is used for comparison. And even IComparare is generic with type of this property. .. maybe implementing the sorting by itself and return object itself from function? That might work.

Comment: @Euphoric - Yes, I just noticed that there is no `IComparable` in the signature (which is strange, how do you sort on a type that is not `IComparable`?). However, `OrderBy()` accepts both `Func<T, object>` and `Func<T, IComparable>`. You don't have to write anything yourself for that.

Comment: @Euphoric - I created an example: http://pastebin.com/ymuDxCM8

Answer (score 2):

Use reflection :)

```
customerList = (sortDirection == "ASC")
   ? customerList
        .OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(sortBy).GetValue(x, null))
        .Skip(startIndex)
        .Take(pageSize)
        .ToList()
   : customerList
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(sortBy).GetValue(x, null))
        .Skip(startIndex)
        .Take(pageSize)
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you simply want to order by the property name as a string. In which case, this is actually already solved by using "Dynamic LINQ":

[Dynamic LINQ OrderBy on IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby)

Take a look at this question's answer and it should provide you with sample code to solve your problem.