# How to sort a List in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class:

```
public class MyObject
{
public string Name;
public int Age;
}
```

I have a List of Myobject objects:

```
Name Age
ABC 12
BBC 14
ABC 11
```

How to sort this list with condition: sort Name first & sort Age later. With this list, the result after sorting:

```
Name Age
ABC 11
ABC 12
BBC 14
```

Comment: I have another question at here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279248/help-me-to-combine-sorting-filtering-on-a-list

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<MyObject>(new[]
        {
            new MyObject { Name = "ABC", Age = 12 },
            new MyObject { Name = "BBC", Age = 14 },
            new MyObject { Name = "ABC", Age = 11 },
        });
        var sortedList = from element in list
                         orderby element.Name
                         orderby element.Age
                         select element;

        foreach (var item in sortedList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.Name, item.Age);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Two different ways using LINQ:

1) Using [**`OrderBy`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) and [**`ThenBy`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby.aspx):

```
l = l.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ThenBy(x => x.Age).ToList();
```

2) Using the query syntax:

```
l = (from x in l
     orderby x.Name, x.Age
     select x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `System.Linq` you can acheive it easily:

```
list = list.OrderBy(e=>e.Name).ThenBy(e=>e.Age);
```

Also check this answer: [Sorting a list using Lambda/Linq to objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722868/sorting-a-list-using-lambda-linq-to-objects).

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following using LINQ:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>();

        list.Add(new MyObject() { Age = 12, Name = "ABC" });
        list.Add(new MyObject() { Age = 11, Name = "ABC" });
        list.Add(new MyObject() { Age = 14, Name = "BBC" });

        var sorted = list.OrderBy(mo => mo.Name).ThenBy(mo => mo.Age);

        foreach (var myObject in sorted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}",
                              myObject.Name, myObject.Age));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an new Object to Order By so that it Orders By that

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<MyObject>(new[]
        {
            new MyObject { Name = "ABC", Age = 12 },
            new MyObject { Name = "BBC", Age = 14 },
            new MyObject { Name = "ABC", Age = 11 },
        });
        var sortedList = list.OrderBy( x => new { x.Name , x.Age });

        foreach (var item in sortedList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.Name, item.Age);
        }
    }
}
```