# Sorting object list by string property C#

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Sorting a list using Lambda/Linq to objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722868/sorting-a-list-using-lambda-linq-to-objects)
>   [C# List<> OrderBy Alphabetical Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188141/c-list-orderby-alphabetical-order)

How do I go about sorting a list of objects in alphabetical order by a string property.

I have tried implementing IComparable on the property but I only figured out how to sort on the first character (using char).

EDIT: Here is some sample code.

```
class MyObject {
    public string MyProperty {get;set;}
}

List<MyObject> sampleList = new List<MyObject>();    

MyObject sample = new MyObject();
sample.MyProperty = "Aardvark";

MyObject sample2 = new MyObject();
sample2.MyProperty = "Zebra";

sampleList.Add(sample);
sampleList.Add(sample2);

sampleList.Sort(); // or something similar

foreach (var item in sampleList) {
    Console.WriteLine(item.MyProperty);
}
```

Should output Aardvark and Zebra (in alphabetical order).

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722868/sorting-a-list-using-lambda-linq-to-objects

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get a sorted `IEnumerable<MyObject>` like so:

```
var sortedQuery = sampleList.OrderBy(x => x.MyProperty);
```

You can then either convert the query to a list like so:

```
var sortedList = sortedQuery.ToList();
```

Or, you can just iterate through the items:

```
foreach (var obj in sortedQuery)
    Console.WriteLine(obj.MyProperty);
```

Answer (score 22):

You can do it using Comparision delegate, using `Sort(Comparision<T> comparision)` overload.

```
list.Sort((a, b) =>  a.StringProperty.CompareTo(b.StringProperty));
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your collection implements the `IEnumerable` interface, you can simply call the `OrderBy` method on your collection:

```
myCollection.OrderBy(c => c.Property);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var list = new List<SomeClass>();
// add some instances of SomeClass to list
list.Sort((x, y) => x.SomeProperty.CompareTo(y.SomeProperty));
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert the code to C# ,

If you have an list object ABC with a string property S for each objects in the list ,

Dim Mylist As New List(Of ABC)

```
    Dim a = From i In Mylist _
           Order By i.S Ascending
```

you will have teh result in a , put on a iterator .

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include System.Collections.Generic and System.Linq.

```
    List<myItemType> lst = new List<myItemType>();
    return lst.OrderBy(i => i.StringPropertyName);
```

Comment: Hi Jason - it returns an enumerable instance where the enumeration will be ordered.   I suppose you could do lst = new List<myItemType>(lst.OrderBy(...));