# Dynamic Orderby function

Tags: c#, linq, generics

In my "Invoice" class it has 20+ fields, I need to support sorting to all fields.

I have a method accepting a string of the property (e.g. "AmountDue"). Now I need to OrderBy AmoundDue field.

My specific requirement is, passing a property name string value I want to return a function like,

`Func<Invoice, decimal> keySelector = a=> a.AmountDue`;

Where whole expression is dynamically built.

where I can use the `keySelector` for for sorting

```
_api.Invoices.Find().Where(c => c.Contact.Id == contactId).OrderBy(keySelector).ToList();
```

So far I was able to identify the type with the string value. Need some help to return a function.

```
  public static Type VariableType(string prop)
    {
        Type type = typeof(TResource);
        PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty(prop, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        type = pi.PropertyType;
        return type;
    }
```

> I referred to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet) before I post this question. Inputs being
>   considered are the same both questions, but outputs are different. I
>   tried to  use that solution and played around, but could not solve my
>   specific problem.  In my case I am calling a third party API (Xero
>   api) and I want to build this output specifically.

Comment: what provider you use? linq to objects or something else?

Comment: Try using Dynamic LINQ.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic LINQ OrderBy on IEnumerable<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet)

Comment: This method is inside an API that I am writing. User will pass any property (string) and I need to convert into objects and do the sorting. Well I can use bunch of if conditions (if propname.ToLower() == "amountdue" then a=>a.AmountDue). But I am trying to avoid this nested if conditions if I can use generics or some other approach to convert the string to nessasary objects.

Comment: I cannnot use Dynamic Linq as I am calling a third party API which does not accept dynamic linq input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sorting you have to return *property value*, not *type* or *property* itself

```
  String propertyName = "AmountDue";

  var result = _context
    .Invoices
    .Find()
    .Where(c => c.Contact.Id == contactId)
    .OrderBy(item => typeof(Invoice).GetProperty(
         propertyName, 
         BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
       .GetValue(item))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the object to the reflection function and return the appropriate property, something like this:

```
.OrderBy(o => keySelector(o, propertyName))

public static Type VariableType(object o, string prop)
{
    Type type = typeof(TResource);
    PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty(prop, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    return pi.GetValue(o);
}
```

But I don't think this would work on `IQueryable` though, because it cannot translate the function into SQL. So you'd have to first execute the query (e.g. with `ToList()`)

```
_context.Invoices.Find().Where(c => c.Contact.Id == contactId).ToList().OrderBy(o => keySelector(o, propertyName)).ToList();
```

Using `dynamic LINQ` as Grundy suggested in a comment would probably be the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You probably would also want to be able to switch between the Sorting Directions (Ascending, Descending). This would bring you to another problem. With some little changes, you should be able to adapt your solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12322548/265165).

The usage is then pretty simple, just call the Extension method `OrderBy<T>` on your collection. This is also where the piece of code is which you were looking for.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Next issue is the order by method. But I can live with one if-else condition since I can dynamically build the hard part.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reflection you could do a simple lookup in a dictionary.

```
static readonly Dictionary<string, Func<Invoice, decimal>> keySelectors = ...;
```

On startup (or using Lazy) you initialize all the keySelectors:

```
keySelectors.Add("AmountDue", a=> a.AmountDue);
// add all 20 options here
```

And now each time you need one it's just a fast dictionary lookup.

Advantages:

- Decouples the string used to connect the UI and the business logic from the field names allowing them to be safely refactored.
- Is easy for other developers on team to understand and maintain.