# LINQ - Sorting a custom list

Tags: linq, sorting

I want to do the same as explained here:
[Sorting a list using Lambda/Linq to objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722868/sorting-a-list-using-lambda-linq-to-objects)

that is:

```
public enum SortDirection { Ascending, Descending }
public void Sort<TKey>(ref List<Employee> list,
                   Func<Employee, TKey> sorter, SortDirection direction)
{
     if (direction == SortDirection.Ascending)
         list = list.OrderBy(sorter);
     else
         list = list.OrderByDescending(sorter);
}
```

to call it he said to do:

Sort(ref employees, e => e.DOB, SortDirection.Descending);

but I do not understand what TKey is refering to and as I can see in the call it is missed the generic TKey.

Could you explain me what is TKey and how to use it?

I suppose I can use another name for the method, it is not necessary to be Sort, right?

thanks!

Comment: Your code will not work. You will have to change it to: ` list = list.OrderBy(sorter).ToList();`.
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *sort by the key* which is of type `TKey` and must implement `IComparable<TKey>`. For instance:

```
// key: Firstname
// TKey: string (which is IComparable<String>
list.OrderBy(person => person.Firstname);
```

The above code sorts *by firstname*, which is what you define using the `sorter`. And yes, you can give your method any name you like. It does not have to be named `Sort`.

**Improvement Suggestion (indirectly related to the question)**

instead of changing `list` and passing it as a reference I'd suggest you to consider the following implementation:

```
public IOrderedEnumerable<Employee> Sort<TKey>(IEnumerable<Employee> list, Func<Employee, TKey> sorter, SortDirection direction);
{
    IOrderedEnumerable<Employee> result;
    if (direction == SortDirection.Ascending)
        result = list.OrderBy(sorter);
    else
        result = list.OrderByDescending(sorter);
    return result;
}
```

You could then return a *new ordered enumerable* of `Employee` objects instead of changing the old one and use *any enumerable* instead of `List` object only. This gives you more flexibility and is closer to the LINQ implementation which people tend to be used to.

Comment: Great!I did what you said and it works like a charm! thanks very much!