# How to Sort Typed List Collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have class like

```
public class ProgressBars
{
    public ProgressBars()
    { }
    private Int32 _ID;
    private string _Name;
    public virtual Int32 ID {get { return _ID; } set { _ID = value; } }
    public virtual string Name { get { return _Name; } set { _Name = value; }}
}
```

here is List collection

```
List<ProgressBars> progress;
progress.Sort //I need to get sort here by Name
```

how can I sort this collection by Name?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provided that you can use LINQ

```
progress = progress.OrderBy(b => b.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: I am not using linq instead of type collection. I am not getting progress.orderby. This is not helpful.

Comment: The question is not whether you are using LINQ but whether you can use LINQ, i.e. whether you're running on .NET 3.5. If this is the case, you might just be missing the namespace System.Linq ;)

Comment: b here is an argument passed to lambda-function

Answer (score 2):

Related questions:

- [linq Order By for a List(Of myObjects)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606997/linq-order-by-for-a-listof-myobjects)
- [Sorting a list using Lambda/Linq to objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722868/sorting-a-list-using-lambda-linq-to-objects)

Comment: I am not using linq instead of type collection.

Comment: omg. then use .Sort() method, which obligates you to implement comparer or comparison: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx

Comment: and look at the links at my answer again with more attention. your comments to @Thomas's answer shows that you don't understand how LINQ and lambda works - so you following answer and msdn have to read about them.

Answer (score 1):

Implement Icomparable interface and ur done

public class ProgressBars : IComparable

{

```
    public ProgressBars()
    { }
    private Int32 _ID;
    private string _Name;
    public virtual Int32 ID { get { return _ID; } set { _ID = value; } }
    public virtual string Name { get { return _Name; } set { _Name = value; } }

    public int CompareTo(ProgressBars obj)
    {
        return _Name.CompareTo(obj.Name);
    }        
}
```

Comment: yep, this is also 1 approach, but that's old and now Linq provide very cool feature and we don't need to this. I am upvoting to this 1, becoz you are right this is one way.