# How to apply a LINQ (l2s) query to a list of entites?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I imported a number of CSVs in a database, each is now a table with some common columns. I'm trying to figure out if I can use Linq2Sql to combine them together without doing a copy/modify.

I've never done anything like [Dynamic LINQ Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693526/dynamic-linq-queries)
Is that the only thing I can do or are there other options?

The query is:

```
var excelRows = 
    from c in Apr10s // <-- GOAL - run on Apr10s, May10s, Jun10s, ... etc....
    where
        c.VolumeStats != null
        && c.VolumeStats > 0
        && c.Costperunit != null
        && c.Costperunit > 0
    select new
    {
        c.Publisher,
        c.CampaignNumber,
        c.Campaign,
        c.RevenuePerUnit,
        c.Costperunit,
        c.VolumeStats,
        c.Rep
    };
var reportItems =
    from c in excelRows
    select new
    {
        Publisher = c.Publisher,
        Campaign = c.Campaign,
        Payout = c.Costperunit,
        Actions = c.VolumeStats,
        Revenue = (decimal)c.Costperunit.Value * (decimal)c.VolumeStats.Value
    };

var reportItemsByPublisher = reportItems.GroupBy(c => c.Publisher);
```

Comment: If this is a one-time thing aren't you better off just writing a SQL script to consolidate the data?

Comment: It's true.  It would be nice if I could produce some re-usable code though because they might ask me to do this again.

Answer (score 0):

Not too easily. If you were using Linq to Entites it's very simple to select from a table using a runtime variable table name. Linq to Sql is more of a challenge.

You might instead considering writing a stored proc or a view that consolidates all the data in your database. This is a data issue, not an application issue, right?

edit: if you want to use the Entity Framework, you have a variety of options. The first is
[executing SQL & returning objects](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/01/08/entity-framework-first-steps/).

Alternatively, create an object and return it from your context for each table something like this

```
using (var c = new myContext())
{
    var result1 = c.CreateObjectSet<MyType>("table1");
    result1.Where(x => blah).Select(y => etc)

    var result2 = c.CreateObjectSet<MyType>("table2");
    var result3 = c.CreateObjectSet<MyType>("table3");
}
```

Comment: I'm happy to switch to EF - can you point me to the corresponding documentation of the feature you refer?